# How to get both .key and .crt files to set up an HTTPS server?

Tags: ios, node.js, express, https

So I need to setup an Https server with express/node.js. 
The sample code related to the topic I find is like(node.js):

```
var options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('.keys/server.key'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('.keys/server.crt'),
  requestCert: true,
  ca: [fs.readFileSync('./keys/ca.crt')]
};
```

express:

```
var options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('.keys/server.key'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('.keys/server.crt'),
  passphrase: '1234'
};
```

So my question is simply how to generate those 2 files (server.key, server.crt) with Openssl?

Not that matters, but this server is only setup for releasing iOS enterprise app's ipa file. I don't really care about security, just Apple requires Https rather than Http.

Answer (score 0):

The command stated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10176685/2518285) will generate two files, key.pem and cert.pem, just rename them to server.key and server.crt (or use these names in the command). Note that this generates a self-signed certificate.